# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/Bootstrapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am not able to run my project. While running I am getting below error (see the error log). Could anyone please help what will be the issue here? It seems like a version mismatch issue.

Error log

```
10:09:40.437 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/Bootstrapper
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor.getTextEncryptor(DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at com.hp.it.os.warrantyorch.Application.main(Application.java:19)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
```

I have added log file here and as well as my pom.xml file.

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hp.it.psoit</groupId>
    <artifactId>warrantyorch</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>warrantyorch</name>
    <version>v1</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <jaxb2.version>1.11.1</jaxb2.version>
        <threetenbp.version>2.10.0</threetenbp.version>
        <openfeign.version>3.0.1</openfeign.version>
        <soap.version>11.8</soap.version>
        <hc5.version>10.12</hc5.version>
        <feign.okhttp.version>12.3</feign.okhttp.version>
        <resilience4j.version>2.0.2</resilience4j.version>
        <spi.version>2.17.224</spi.version>
        <aws.crt.version>0.21.14</aws.crt.version>
        <crt.client.version>2.20.25</crt.client.version>
        <sdk-core.version>2.20.25</sdk-core.version>
        <jwt.version>4.2.1</jwt.version>
        <rsa.version>0.21.2</rsa.version>
        <commonlib.version>0.4.85</commonlib.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hp.os</groupId>
            <artifactId>commonlib</artifactId>
            <version>${commonlib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${threetenbp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-soap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>${openfeign.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-soap</artifactId>
            <version>${soap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-hc5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-hc5</artifactId>
            <version>${hc5.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${feign.okhttp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AOP LOG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-client-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${spi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk.crt</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-crt</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.crt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-crt-client</artifactId>
            <version>${crt.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>${sdk-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
            <version>${rsa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The Spring Cloud version in use is not compatible with Spring Boot 3.